# Matching a json field with a name that contains spaces or special charecters with Jsonata

Tags: json, jsonata

Lets say I have some JSON like:

```
{
  "normal": 1,
  "has some spaces": 2,
  "@": 3
}
```

I can get the value of the `normal` field with the simple query:

```
normal
```

However I can't get the other two fields. I have tried:

```
[has some spaces]
'has some spaces'
['has some spaces']
"has some spaces"
["has some spaces"]
{has some spaces}
{'has some spaces'}
{"has some spaces"}
```

but none of them work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was resolved for me by the maintainer on a [github issue I raised](https://github.com/jsonata-js/jsonata/issues/466) :

> Under the [Navigating JSON Objects section](https://docs.jsonata.org/simple#navigating-json-objects), the following is listed:
>
> > Field references containing whitespace or reserved tokens can be enclosed in backticks

...

> then the JSONata expressions `` `has some spaces` `` and `` `@` `` will match 2 and 3 respectively.

But not before I discovered two alternatives by trial and error:

```
$."has some spaces"
```

and

```
$.'has some spaces'
```