# Adaptive Card Templating JSON Key with Space

Tags: json, chatbot, templating, adaptive-cards

I'm having trouble using an API response for data in regards to Adaptive Card templating because some of the keys have spaces. Here's an example:

Data

```
{
  "General": {
    "Computer Name": "Computer-Name",
    "IP Address": "x.x.x.x",
    "Description": "person@example.com",
    "Icon": 2,
  },
  "Operating System": {
    "Name": "Computer-Name",
    "Version": "Microsoft Windows 11 Pro - 21H2/22000",
    "Architecture": "64-bit"
  },
  "BIOS": {
    "Vendor": "Microsoft Corporation",
    "Version": "9.106.140"
  },
  "Motherboard": {
    "Vendor": "Microsoft Corporation",
    "Name": "Surface Laptop 3",
    "CPU": "Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1035G7 CPU @ 1.20GHz",
    "GPU1": "Intel(R) Iris(R) Plus Graphics"
  },
  "Memory": {
    "BANK 0": {
      "Capacity/Speed": "4096 Mb, 4267 Mhz",
      "Part Number": "Samsung, K4U6E3S4AA-MGCL     "
    },
    "BANK 2": {
      "Capacity/Speed": "4096 Mb, 4267 Mhz",
      "Part Number": "Samsung, K4U6E3S4AA-MGCL     "
    }
  },
  "Storage": {
    "KBG40ZNS256G TOSHIBA MEMORY": {
      "Capacity": "244191Mb"
    }
  }
}
```

How would I access, for example the Computer Name field under General in an adaptive card template? I've tried ${General."Computer Name"} both with single and double quotes, and also with and without brackets. I've been beating my head against the wall on this for a while so anyhelp would be appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63302154/109941)?

[image: How to deal with JSON properties with spaces]

[Reference](https://docs.jsonata.org/simple#navigating-json-objects)

Comment: I just tried in in the Adaptive Card designer and it doesn't like it. Good thought though. Could just be a designer flaw too I'll have to test another way.